# Using an Excel file from onedrive in c#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a program that uses an excel file to get some data.

I'm trying to make it so i can update data while the application is running, but i have no clue on how to get the file from onedrive.

The application is running c# .net 6. Reading the data from a local path is no issue.

I want to know if there is a better way than onedrive, or how i would read the excel data.

Scenario: The application will run on a remote server. I need to update the excel file from my own pc. I would rather have the file locally and have onedrive automatically syncing it on the machine, than having to remote desktop to the server.

**UPDATE:**
I've now tried troubleshooting and it seems like the path can't be found. I've written the path in console to see if it uses the correct path on the server as well, when using path in file explorer, i go directly to the file.

Comment: How do you want to obtain the file contents from OneDrive? Is the file synced by Windows itself to a local directory already, or are you using an API to get the file contents?

Comment: On the server i'm logged in and the file is stored as on the path "C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop"

But trying to use this path directly i get an error

Comment: Is the file set to keep a copy locally?

Comment: No clue Is it just checking the "always keep on this device"? In that case, yes, and it still don't work with the file

Comment: According to [OneDrive API Endpoint Differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/direct-endpoint-differences?source=recommendations&view=odsp-graph-online): _Microsoft Graph is the preferred endpoint for accessing OneDrive personal, OneDrive for Business, and SharePoint online files._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So having this issue i was not thinking about the posibility of not having the rights to access the file.

To fix the issue i had to go into application pools and then edit the application pool i was using, for that service, to a user having rights to the folder it tried to access.